# UIView doesn't respond to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have simple view controller and I add this controller like subview for window using this code:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];

self.view.alpha = 0.0;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[window addSubview:self.view];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeTriggered:)]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
  self.view.alpha = 1.0;
    }completion:nil];
```

But when I click at this view - nothing happens. Even event touchesBegan: are not called.

UPD:
Code above is in -(void)show method. I want to show one controller above all controllers.
In FirstViewController I create instance of CustonAlertViewController like that:

```
CustomAlertViewController *alertVC = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc]init];
[alertVC show];
```

In CustomAlertViewController I have show method presented at the top and viewDidLoad method with:

```
self.view.backgrondColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: what is frame of self.view

Comment: i have tested you code and is working perfectly no issue in code

Comment: @PKT I set frame like self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

Comment: @PKT It is something strange, but thanks for your comment

Comment: but your code is working  no issue with that where you put that code ?

Comment: self.view is your default view or custom

Comment: @PKT I put that code into -(void)show method and call in from another viewController. This code shows my controller, but I can't catch any touch events there

Comment: @PKT self.view is a view of a viewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111875/discussion-between-ostap-holub-and-pkt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden views (and equivalently, those with `alpha == 0.0`) do not respond to touches.  If you require a fully transparent view, leave alpha as > 0.0, and say...

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Alternatively, assign a nonzero alpha.

**EDIT** yes, the `CustomAlertViewController` instance is being deallocated immediately after `show` is invoked.  The view controller that does the allocating needs to have a strong property to keep the alert around,

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) CustomAlertViewController *alertVC;
```

and adding...

```
CustomAlertViewController *alertVC = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc]init];
self.alertVC = alertVC;
[alertVC show];
```

This doesn't try to address some potential problems beyond the scope of this question (like rotation, or cleanly restoring when the alert is done).

Comment: I set alpha to 1.0, but it still doesn't response

Comment: Just looked again at your code.  Are you certain that view is even on the window?  Try `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` using something like red, so we can be sure its even there.

Comment: Yes, my view is on the window. In viewDidLoad I set self.view.backgroundColor to greenColor

Comment: Are you sure the view controller isn't being orphaned?  In that view controller, please implement `- (void)dealloc { NSLog(@"this can't be good"); }`.  If you see that message on the console, we'll understand the problem.

Comment: Yes. I get this message in console. Does it mean that my controller is dealloc right after allocation?

Comment: Not sure when, but it's being deallocated.  Can you edit your OP to explain what you're trying to accomplish and how you're handling the view controller.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is great! I totally forgot about ARC and strong references.

Answer (score 0):

// try like this , u need to give number of touches

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeTriggered:)];
 gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Comment: then , ithink  some otherview ovelapped on your view

Answer (score 0):

You have been setting your `UITapGestureRecognizer` after you `addSubview` to your window. like:

**You have been doing this**

```
//...
[window addSubview:self.view];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeTriggered:)]];
//...
```

**Try this**

Set `UITapGestureRecognizer` before you `addSubview`. And remember to add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your `ViewController`

```
self.view.alpha = 0.2;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeTriggered:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

// After you add your self.view to window
[window addSubview:self.view];
```

I hope this can help you.